# Repository pattern to get data from dbset.local or database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am writing a method which will loop over some data and create records in a database, the method makes use of a repository.

Originally it was something like this:

```
///Lets assume that there is a string array called arr somewhere above this.
var repo = new ItemRepository();

for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
{
    if (repo.MyItems.Count(x=>x.ID == arr[i]) == 0)
    {
        //Doesn't Exist Create
        repo.MyItems.Add(new Item(arr[i]));
        repo.Save();
    }
    else
    {
       //Here I will get an instance of the entity that already exists and do some updates to it
    }
}
```

Which worked but because it was saving to the DB with every iteration it was quite slow, so what I want to do is change it to something like this:

```
var repo = new ItemRepository();

for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
{
    if (repo.MyItems.Count(x=>x.ID == arr[i]) == 0)
    {
        //Doesn't Exist Create
        repo.MyItems.Add(new Item(arr[i]));
    }
    else
    {
       //Here I will get an instance of the entity that already exists and do some updates to it
    }

}

repo.Save();
```

So that the save is only done AFTER all of the entities have been created, so its one big DB insert rather than thousands.

The problem is that because the items have not been persisted back to my database the repo.MyItems.Count(x=>x.ID == i) doesn't bring anything back (Although the entities have been added to the dbset.Local collection.

I suppose my question is how can I modify my repository to allow me to query the local collection AND the database - because that's the kicker, they may exist in the database OR they may have already been added to the repository and not inserted into the database.

The above is pseudo code, but kind of represents what I am doing, the repository method is something like

```
public int count(string val)
{
    IQueryable<T> data = _dbSet;

    return data.Count(x=>x.COLUMNNAME == val);
}
```

Again this is only a representation of what I have in the repo  but it should give some idea of what I am going for.

Comment: That's not the repository pattern. That's an useless abstraction over DbSet. Actually, that code looks more like of what a repository implementation should be. But probably you don't need a repository in your use case.

Comment: And the award for most constructive comment goes to... :)

This is an abstraction of dbSet because we keep the UI and BL layers agnostic to the persistence layer so they don't directly interact with the entity framework.

The code shown above is not from the system I am working on it is simplified pseudo code to convey what I am trying to do.

Would be interested though in your opinion on what an implementation of the repository pattern should look like.. If Im doing it wrong I want to know about it! :)

Comment: UI might know, but the BL shouldn't know about DbSet or anything related to EF [insert whatever DAO or db]. Your 'repository' doesn't add any value and it's leaking. There's no 'repository.Items.Add/Count ' . There should be just 'repository.Add(aLotOfBusinessObjects)'. What you're doing here is just using EF hidden under abstractions. But the mindset and code is EF. Quick test: pretend you're switching to Azure Tables, the only thing that should change is the repository implementation, not the interface , not the code invoking the repository.

Comment: The point of RP is to to decouple BL from _everything_ persistence. This means you can change everything persistence (db, ORM) and the rest of the app would work without a hitch. It doesn't mean that you will change the db in practice, it does mean that your app really doesn't know about persistence details.

Comment: Hi, Yeah, what youre describing is what we have in the actual system, I agree that the quickly thrown together code that I put in the question is not correct, however it was just thrown together to give an example of what I am trying to do in a very cut down simplistic way - rather than trying to talk through the few hundred lines of code involved in the actual operation that I am working on at the moment.

Thanks for your input, its appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any one is interested, this is what I implemented and it seemed to work, however I ended up giving up on it as realised that this would pretty much be allowing "Dirty Reads" of the data which had a knock on effect on the rest of the system and we decided that the performance hit of multiple saves was more desirable than reworking big bits of the system - or implementing a repo that allows dirty reads...

Note that GetSingle replaces the Count that I had in the pseudo code above.

```
public T GetSingle(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        //Check the local collection first

        IQueryable<T> localEntities = _dbset.Local.AsQueryable();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            localEntities = localEntities.Where(filter);
        }

        if (localEntities.Count() > 0)
        {
            return localEntities.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            //A local version of this was not found - try the database.

            IQueryable<T> query = this._dbset;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }            
    }
```

If there is a better way to do this I would really like to know as this is an issue that I am probably going to encounter again and next time I might need to follow through with it!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the problem correctly, this is what I usually do:

```
        var repo = new ItemRepository();

        Int32 index = 0;
        Int32 localIndex = 0;
        while (index < arr.Length) {
            repo.MyItems.Add(new Item(arr[index]));
            index++;
            localIndex++;
            if (localIndex == 1000) {
                repo.Save();
                localIndex = 0;
            }
        }
        if (localIndex > 0) {
            repo.Save();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, not quite what I was after as its not checking the repo for the existence of entities before adding new ones.

The reason that this is important (I omitted it from the code above to retain simplicity) is that if 
`repo.MyItems.Count(x=>x.ID == arr[i])` returns more than one then that entity will be updated - in this case some child entities will be attached.

Comment: I have updated the code to show where the update is happening.